# Appending variable to text file not working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my program to output two variables to a text file after it finishes running something but all I get is the folder and no text files inside of it. Here is the code in question:

I have edited to include the entire program.

```html
import random #needed for the random question creation
import os #needed for when the scores will be appended to a text file
#import csv #work in progress
answer = 0 #just to ensure a strage error isn't created by the input validation (since converting to a global variable isn't really needed)
global questionnumber #sets the question number to be a global variable so that 
questionnumber = 0
global score
score = 0
global name
name = "a"
def check_input(user_input): #used to verify that input by user is a valid number
    try: #the condition that does the checking
        answer = int (user_input)
    except ValueError: #what to do if the number isn't actually a number
        return fail() #calls the failure message
    return answer #sends the answer back to the rest of the program
def fail(): #the failure message procedure defined
   print("That isn't a whole number! Try again with a different question") #tells the user what's going on
   global questionnumber #calls the global variable for this procedure
   questionnumber = questionnumber - 1 #allows the user, who made a mistake, a second chance to get it right
def questions(): #the question procedure defined
    global name
    name=input("Enter your name: ") #gets the user's name for logging and also outputting messages to them
    print("Hello there",name,"! Please answer 10 random maths questions for this test!") #outputs welcome message to the user
    ClassOfStudent=input("Which class are you in?") #gets the user's class for logging
    finish = False
    while finish == False: #only occurs if "finish" isn't set to true so that the questions asked don't exceed ten
        global questionnumber #calls the global variable
        global score
        choice = random.choice("+-x") #uses the random function to choose the operator
        if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0: #validation to ensure the question number is within ten
            number1 = random.randrange(1,12) #uses random numbers from the random function, above 1 and below 12
            number2 = random.randrange(1,12) #same as the abovem for the second number
            print((number1),(choice),(number2)) #outputs the sum for the student to answer
            answer=check_input((input("What is the answer?"))) #asks for the student's answer
            questionnumber = questionnumber + 1 #adds one to the numebvr of questions asked

            if choice==("+"): #if the ramdomly generated operator was plus
                correctanswer = number1+number2 #operator is used with the numbers to work out the right answer
                if answer==correctanswer: #checks the studen't answer is right
                    print("That's the correct answer") #if it is, it tells the student
                    score = score + 1 #adds one to the score that the user has
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",correctanswer,"!") #if the answer is wrong, it tells the student and doesn't add one to the score

            if choice==("x"): #essentially the same as the addition, but with a multiplicatin operator instead
                correctanswer = number1*number2
                if answer==correctanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    score = score + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",correctanswer,"!")

            elif choice==("-"): #essentially the same as the addition, but with a subtraction operator instead
                correctanswer = number1-number2

                if answer==correctanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    score = score + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",correctanswer,"!")
        else: #if the number of questions asked is ten, it goes on to end the program
            finish = True
    else:
            print("Good job",name,"! You have finished the quiz") #outputs a message to the user to tell them that they've finished the quiz
            print("You scored " + str(score) + "/10 questions.") #ouputs the user's score to let them know how well they've done
            #all below here is a work in progress
            #Create a new directory for the scores to go in, if it is not there already.
            if os.path.exists("Scores") == False:
              os.mkdir("Scores")
            os.chdir("Scores")
            if ClassOfStudent==1: #write scores to class 1 text
                file_var = open("Class 1.txt",'w+')
                file_var.write("name, score")
                file_var.close()
            if ClassOfStudent==2: #write score to class 2 text
                file_var = open("Class 2.txt",'w+')
                file_var.write(name, score)
                file_var.close()
            if ClassOfStudent==3: #write score to class 3 text
                file_var = open("Class 3.txt",'w+')
                file_var.write(name, score)
                file_var.close()
questions()
```

Comment: indentation in python is critical. Your problem is almost certainly related to how you have your if statements indented. We can't see what your code actually looks like, so please take the time to get it right.

Comment: If you don't get any of the files created then that would imply none of your `if ClassOfStudent==something:` conditions is `True` and it has some other value. My guess would be that you read it from some input as a string and never converted it to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `print(repr(ClassOfStudent))` to show the value and type:

```
>>> ClassOfStudent = input("Which class are you in?")
Which class are you in?2
>>> print(repr(ClassOfStudent))
'2'
```

Using `input()` in Python 3 will read the value in as a string. You need to either convert it to an `int` or do the comparison against a string.

```
ClassOfStudent = int(input("Which class are you in?")
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassOfStudent` is a string rather than a number, so none of the code that writes to the file will get executed. You can easily verify that by adding a `print` statement under each `if` so you can see if that code is being executed.

The solution is to compare to strings, or convert `ClassOfStudent` to an i teger.

Answer (score 0):

first you have a problem with the "". you have to correct the following:

```
if ClassOfStudent==2: #write scores to class 1 text
            file_var = open("Class 2.txt",'w+')
            file_var.write("name, score")
            file_var.close()
if ClassOfStudent==3: #write scores to class 1 text
            file_var = open("Class 3.txt",'w+')
            file_var.write("name, score")
            file_var.close()
```

notice that I added the "" inside the write.
In any case, I think what you want is something like:
file_var.write("name %s, score %s"%(name,score)). This should be more appropriate.