# Python storing data, High Scores

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, text-files

I am writing code for a maths quiz and in this quiz I need to be able to store the data to a text file. The data being the scores at the end of the quiz. I need it to output into a text file like this...

```
> Tom,4,5,7 
> Evie,6,10,8
```

So far I only have this

```
import random
Class=input("What class are you in?")
name=input("What is your name?")
print("Welcome to the maths quiz",name)
print("Try to answer all the questions with the correct number.")
score=0
questionnumber=0
while questionnumber<10:
        Number1=random.randrange(1,10)
        Number2=random.randrange(1,10)
        Operation=random.randrange(1,4)
        if(Operation==1):
                symbol= " + "
                correctAnswer = Number1 + Number2
        elif(Operation==2):
                symbol= " - "
                correctAnswer = Number1 - Number2
        else:
                symbol= " * "
                correctAnswer = Number1 * Number2 
        question=(str(Number1)+str(symbol)+str(Number2)+"=?")
        useranswer=(float(input(question)))
        if useranswer==correctAnswer:
                    score=score+1
                    print("Well Done, Correct. Your score is now ",score,"/10")
                    questionnumber=questionnumber+1                
        else:
                print("Incorrect, sorry. Score:",score)
                questionnumber=questionnumber+1
else:
                    print(name," you finished with a score of ",score,"/10")

if(Class==1):
        fi=open("Class1.txt","a")
        fi.writelines("\n"+name+":"+str(score))
        fi.close
elif (Class== 2):
        fi=open("Class2.txt","a")
        fi.writelines("\n"+name+":"+str(score))
        fi.close
elif (Class== 3):
        fi=open("Class3.txt","a")
        fi.writelines("\n"+name+":"+str(score))
        fi.close
```

The output looks like this...

```
Tom:4
Tom:5
Tom:7
Evie:6
Evie:10
Evie:8
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working as expected?

Comment: where/how are you definig name and score? i would suggest tockenizing your data before inputting it

Comment: It outputs well, however it needs to be outputted csv style like I showed above, I just don't quite know how to do that

Comment: What R Nar is saying, though, is that the code you included isn't showing where you're getting `name` and `score`.

Comment: Please do your own GCSE coursework. If you get stuck, talk to your teacher. If you are going to ask here, at least learn [ask] first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080165/appending-variable-to-text-file-not-working-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential core of what you're looking for is this:

```
fi.writelines("\n"+name+","+ ",".join([str(score) for score in scores])
```

But it is unclear how you're getting your `score` value, so it's unclear how you would properly reference `scores`.